# How to use AWS managed blockchain API services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/APIReference/API_CreateNetwork.html

The Above was the documentation link that I have followed to work with REST services. In this documentation they mentioned about URI, Method type and it's body but they didn't mentioned anything about Base URL. Do we need to create any service to get the base URL in AWS? If possible somebody please explain how to use the REST services mentioned in the above link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AWS managed-blockchain is currently in preview, unless you are a preview user you will not be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, I am a preview user. But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: It had slipped my mind; Blockchain Preview was in maintenance... I just received the email from AWS that the maintenance period is over. Can you try again?